Laravel 9 update Form that contain input file for CV
I have been trying to update a form that has a resume file input. I want users to only change the file if they are make mistake of uploading a wrong resume but the page refrresh and when i debug using dd i can not see in my json respond the cv input with all other fields here is my current code
InterviewController.php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
   {

       
       // Validate the form data
       $request->validate([
           'candidat_name' => 'required|string',
           'poste' => 'required|string',
           'interview_time' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
           'interview_date' => 'required|date',
           'cv' => 'nullable|file|mimes:pdf,doc,docx|max:2048',
           'description' => 'required|string',
       ]);
   
       // Find the existing Interview model instance
       $interview = Interview::findOrFail($id);
   
       // Update interview attributes
       $interview->candidat_name = $request->input('candidat_name');
       $interview->poste = $request->input('poste');
       $interview->interview_time = $request->input('interview_time');
       $interview->interview_date = $request->input('interview_date');
       $interview->description = $request->input('description');
   
       // Handle file upload if a new CV is provided
       if ($request->hasFile('cv')) {
           // Delete the existing CV file if it exists
           if ($interview->cv) {
               Storage::delete('public/' . $interview->cv);
           }
           $cv = $request->file('cv');
           $cvPath = $cv->store('cvs', 'public');
           $interview->cv = $cvPath;
       } else {
           // If no new file is provided, keep the existing file path
           $interview->cv = $interview->cv;
       }
   
       // Save the updated interview
       $interview->save();
   
       // Redirect with a success message
       return redirect()->route('interviews.index')->with('success', 'Interview updated successfully.');
   } 

index.blade.php
Here is my form
@foreach ($interviews as $interview)
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="editModal-{{ $interview->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Modifier Informations</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <svg aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x"><line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line><line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line></svg>
                </button>
            </div>

            
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{ route('interviews.update', $interview->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">                   
                    @csrf
                    @method('PUT')
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="">Candidat</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="candidat_name" id="candidat_name" value="{{ $interview->candidat_name }}" placeholder="Nom & Prénom">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="">Poste</label>
                            <select class="form-select form-control-sm" name="poste" id="poste" required>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Sélectionner Poste</option>
                                @foreach ($jobs as $job)
                                    <option value="{{ $job->poste }}" {{ $interview->poste == $job->poste ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $job->poste }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-2">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="">Heure d'entretien</label>
                            <input type="time" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="interview_time" id="interview_time" value="{{ $interview->interview_time }}" placeholder="Nom & Prénom">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="">Date d'entretien</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="interview_date" id="interview_date" value="{{ $interview->interview_date }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="">Curriculum Vitae</label>
                      
                        <input class="form-control file-upload-input" type="file" name="cv" id="formFile">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group mb-4">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="description">{{ $interview->description }}</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="button" value="{{__('Annuler')}}" class="btn  btn-dark" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                    <input type="submit" value="{{__('Modifier')}}" class="btn  btn-primary">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
@endforeach


After successful updation it redirect to route('interviews.index').So what did you debug using dd(..)?$request->input field right?.and in that case you didn't find cv input filed right?

yes i didn't find the cv input field but i can see other fields.

Since the file-uploads are sent as multipart/form-data they cant be accessed using dd($request->all()).Because files are not handled like other standard request-data.

when i debug using dd($request->all()); // Debug request data i can not see the cv field is present in the request data. what should i do now please becuase i am in this bug for 2 days

even when like i try to udpate the data and uploading a new cv resume i can see the path to that new uploaded cv but when i try to save it it won't save aslo but there is cases i want to update only like the name or interview time and keeo the same resume

Okay now you get to the point. You want to upload the Form with and without resume depending upon input provided to the form?
And that case form upload is not successful.Right?

Just confirm me two things
(1) you want to save your CV in public folder.Right?
(2) where CV is not being saved? is it in your public folder or the file-path that is not saved into database ?
Answer these two question I will post my answer.

yes when i save my cv it saved in my public C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\storage\app\public\cvs the save is going with success the problem i have is in when i try to edit the data

Have you tried the solution that i have posted??

yes i have test that and i still got the same problem

What error you are getting ?Please comment on the answer post

You don't need to use the ..else{..} block. if(){} block  alone will check if a file will be uploaded or not. if no file is getting uploaded then you don't even need to update $interview->cv field since there is no need to fetch the previous value and then updated the DB-column with same value.
As per documentation store() returned the /path-to-the-file.So you also don't need to explicitly define /public in Storage::delete(...)
Please check the the documentation for further information on store().
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/filesystem#file-uploads
As per the conversation in the chat and after your clarification I modified the code given below.Use this code in place of yours code.
if ($request->hasFile('cv')) {
    // Delete the existing CV file if it exists
    if ($interview->cv) {
        Storage::delete($interview->cv);
    }
    $cv = $request->file('cv');
    $cvPath = $cv->store('cvs', 'public');
    $interview->cv = $cvPath;
}

// Save the updated interview
$interview->save();

Try this.I think it will resolve the issue.If not then let me know.

i dont get any error i will explain to you my brother again the behavoir i got when i i store my interview data everything is going good but when i try to update the data like change the name of the interview date or time i can not see that data change

@AbdellahHajjam, just to make sure have you imported these three use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage; use Illuminate\Http\Request;,
use App\Models\Interview; to the top of the Controller?

@AbdellahHajjam, Another fixation you need to make. Add this code  {{ route('interviews.update', ['id'=>$interview->id]) }} to the action attribute of the form in blade template.You should pass the ID as the array format to the form action.

@AbdellahHajjam, another small fixation try with @method('PATCH') in the form.

i have try all this i have change the method to patch and also i have add that route also i already have use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage; use Illuminate\Http\Request;, use App\Models\Interview; in the top of my controller i dont understand why this is not working

can we lunch a chat room o i can share with u my codes again please

Yes sure @AbdellahHajjam.I have pinged you to the previous chat room

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Try to increase the post_max_size value to a higher value.
Try to check the server configuration, like

post_max_size

in

php.ini

file.
Sometimes if the post size (Including file and other form data) increases the setting post size in php.ini file, data will not update.
Surprisingly it will not throw any error.
Note: If you are working local and using Servers like XAMP, WAMP you should restart the services.
